# One of my sprites won't appear in my pygame code

Tags: python, pygame

I made this game which makes some red boxes fly in from the right and you have to dodge them with the black box. Currently, I am trying to make another enemy type that is bigger and slower. I made the class, put it into the sprite group, and it still wont show up. Here is the code. I'v added some comments where I put the things for the new sprite.

```
import pygame, random, time
from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)
print('Use the window above to play')
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600
X = 400
Y = 400
SCREEN_WIDTH = display_width
SCREEN_HEIGHT = display_height
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

def death():
    global alive
    print('You died')
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 100)
    textsurface = myfont.render('You Died', False, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
        self.surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT
#normal enemy class
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.surf.fill((200, 30, 30))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(5, 10)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
#new enemy class
class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bomb, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 25))
        self.surf.fill((100, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(2, 5)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()

ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 250)

player = Player(display_width // 2, display_height // 2)

enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()
bomb = pygame.sprite.Group() #I added it to the sprite group
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

alive = True
while alive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            alive = False

        elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
            new_enemy = Enemy()
            new_bomb = Bomb()
            enemies.add(new_enemy)
            all_sprites.add(new_enemy)
            all_sprites.add(new_bomb) #I made it add a new sprite

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    enemies.update()

    screen.fill((50,50,160))

    for entity in all_sprites:
        screen.blit(entity.surf, entity.rect)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, enemies):
        player.kill()
        alive = False
        death()

    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I found out where it doesn't add the sprite, and fixed it.

```
    elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
        new_enemy = Enemy()
        new_bomb = Bomb()
        enemies.add(new_enemy)
        enemies.add(new_bomb) # I needed to add this
        all_sprites.add(new_enemy)
        all_sprites.add(new_bomb)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you've fixed?